# How to run a python file (.py) from the windows command-line without having to type python first?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, command-line, pycharm

Suppose I have a python file named file.py.
Normally to run this file from the command-line I would do:

```
python path\to\file\file.py
```

My question is, is it possible to do this without having the `python` before the file path like so:

```
path\to\file\file.py
```

Or, if I have the path to file.py in my Environment Variables, simply just:

```
file.py
```

I suppose it's worth noting I want to do this with a python file that is going to accept command-line arguments. Thanks :)

Comment: If you use Cygwin, you can include a hash bang ("#! /usr/bin/env python") and make your file executable ("chmod a+x path/to/file.py") to make it possible to invoke directly within Cygwin. Good luck with the built-in WIndows commandline, though... that interpreter is terrible.

Comment: On Unix or Linux, we have SheBang(or HashBang) like `#!/usr/bin/env python` on the script top. I don't know Windows support this or not.

Comment: Have a look at the docs here : https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable

Comment: Windows, as it says in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is the fact that your python application is not actually an application. It is an interpreted script. This is because Python is an [Interpreted Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language).

This would be similar to you have a Word or Excel document. These are interpreted by their applications: Word and Excel, respectively. The operating system knows what application to use to interpret them using the registered associated programs.

The official Python FAQs explains this here:
https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable

Comment: I would recommend reading that entire page, along with official [Using Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html) page to get more information.